# Find highest consecutive period of 6 months within given 12 months in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm working on building a purchasing / reorder schedule algorithim for our company. Given the following dataset, how would I select the 6 month period that has the highest combined values? (E.G. Jan-June, Feb-July, Mar-Aug, Apr-Sep etc)

```
║ January ║ February ║ March ║ April ║ May ║ June ║ July ║ August ║ September ║ October ║ November ║ December ║
║ 5       ║ 2        ║ 6     ║ 2     ║ 5   ║ 4    ║ 8    ║ 5      ║ 6         ║ 4       ║ 3        ║ 2        ║
```

Obviously this could be achieved by the following, but I'm wanting the code to be a little more flexible, so i could change the values of 6 or 12 as required.

```
(SELECT MAX(Details.Quantity)
      FROM 
    (VALUES 
    SUM(January, February, March, April, May, June),
    SUM(February, March, April, May, June, July),
    SUM(March, April, May, June, July, August),
    SUM(April, May, June, July, August, September),
    SUM(May, June, July, August, September, October),
    SUM(June, July, August, September, October, November),
    SUM(July, August, September, October, November, December)
    ) AS Details(Quantity)) 

   AS Max
```

Answer (score 1):

Mr. Cat was right and here is the SQL to support that.

> I created a Table [MonthIds] which is basically 12 rows January => 1, February => 2.... December => 12

Also the above data would be best represented in Rows rather than Columns, the below example UNPIVOT's the above data, if done as rows you could skip the unpivot

```
SELECT TOP 1 Month AS StartMonth
FROM (
    SELECT [Month],
        [Value],
        SUM([value]) OVER (
            ORDER BY MonthId ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW
                    AND 6 FOLLOWING
            ) AS SumOverPeriod
    FROM (
        SELECT mi.Id AS MonthId,
            [Month],
            [Value]
        FROM (
            SELECT *
            FROM [Months]
            ) m
        UNPIVOT([Value] FOR [Month] IN (
                    [January],
                    [February],
                    [March],
                    [April],
                    [May],
                    [June],
                    [July],
                    [August],
                    [September],
                    [October],
                    [November],
                    [December]
                    )) AS u
        JOIN [MonthIds] mi ON mi.NAME = u.Month
        ) a
    ) s
ORDER BY SumOverPeriod DESC
```

This SQL will give you the Start Month of the 6 Months

You could change **AND 6 FOLLOWING** and replace to whatever number you want.

NOTE
If you change it to 12 then January will always be the 1st month.

Answer (score 0):

i'd probably convert the months to numeric and add a table months with columns id and name, numbered 1..12. then, assuming that this is a trailing 12 month demand history, i'd calculate the trailing 6 month demand for each month and select the top 1 ordered by cumulative demand descending.

if this is an ongoing thing, you can accumulate demand in another table and then recalc each month so your data is fresh.

Answer (score 0):

Main problem is you have ask part of your problem.you should have posted the correct table design with few sample data.

This is same solution which will work in `sql server 2008` and below

```
 create table #t (January int,February int,March int,April int,May int
 ,June int,July int,August int,September int,October int,November int,December int)

 insert into #t VALUES
 (5,2,6,2,5,4,8, 5,6,4,3,2)

 declare @RangeMonth int=6

 ;with CTE as
 (
 select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(order by (select null))rn 
 from #t
  UNPIVOT([Value] FOR [Month] IN (
                    [January],
                    [February],
                    [March],
                    [April],
                    [May],
                    [June],
                    [July],
                    [August],
                    [September],
                    [October],
                    [November],
                    [December]
                    )) AS u
 )
 ,CTE1 AS(
 select [month], rn,value, sumValue from CTE c
 cross apply
 (
 select sum(value) sumValue from cte c1 
 where c1.rn>=c.rn and c1.rn<=c.rn+@RangeMonth
 )ca

 )
 ,CTE2 AS(
 select max(sumvalue)sumvalue from cte1 c1
 )
 ,CTE3 AS(
 select c.* from cte1 c
 cross apply(
 select sumvalue from cte2 c1 where c.sumvalue=c1.sumvalue
 )ca
 )
 select c.* from cte1 c
 cross apply(select * from cte3 c1 where c.rn>=c1.rn and c.rn<=c1.rn+@RangeMonth)ca

 drop table #t
```